# AFNetworkReachabilityStatus does not change from offline to online

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

Using my iOS Simulator, I switch my WIFI on and off on my laptop to test if if AFNetworking properly detects and switches the status. However, in the code below, after switching from offline to online, it always goes to the default case. Why does this happen? Thanks!

```
- (void)startReachabilityService
{
    __weak WKNetworkManager *weakSelf = self;
    __weak NSMutableArray *weakRequestQueue = _requestQueue;

    [self setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    BOOL startExecution = NO;

    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            startExecution = ![weakSelf.currentLogedInUser.isUploadViaWIFI boolValue];
            weakSelf.isConnectionWorking = YES;
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            startExecution = YES;
            weakSelf.isConnectionWorking = YES;
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown:
        default:
            startExecution = NO;
            weakSelf.isConnectionWorking = NO;
            break;
    }

    if (startExecution && weakRequestQueue.count && weakSelf.isQueueRuning == NO) {
        [weakSelf startRequestExecution];
    }
}];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this problem only applies to the iOS Simulator. Once deploying on an actual device, it seems to detect the switch fine.